# Facebook app showing blank page for the canvas url under facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I want to show a website under facebook, so is created a Application on facebook and it's settings as follows -

> 1. provided namespace name as storeappdev
> 2. added "App on Facebook" platform, and for it set canvas url as http://joomla.programminghelp24.com/ and likewise entered secure canvas
>      url with https.Also apprehended unchangeable canvas url as
>      https://apps.facebook.com/storeappdev.

But when want to go for testing the appearances by typing https://apps.facebook.com/storeappdev/ in browser, i see a blank page! not the website as i set canvas url.I just can't get this url https://apps.facebook.com/storeappdev/ loaded without https.So to remove it, i disabled secure browsing from my fb account's security settings and so is i get the url loaded without https and i see site loaded within facebook.But this is not expected, as i want to have secure browsing enabled.So in that case how do i make it work??

I found some similar posts by google search but none worked out specifically, so please suggest, however, i see that now that fb using secure url by defeult as -  https://apps.facebook.com/storeappdev/ which was not set before.

Comment: Do you enable your project to be access by the world? In developers.facebook.com find for the menu: "Status & Review" and check it.

Comment: Yes precisely it was set yes to be public in that app settings

Comment: The SSL certificate that the browser receives for https://joomla.programminghelp24.com/ does not match the server name – and since that page is called within an iframe, some browsers simply reject it without further message. If you call that page directly, outside of facebook.com, then your browser should alert you to the error, and also offer you to accept the certificate nonetheless – after that, it should work inside the iframe as well. (Of course that would be only a solution for yourself for testing – if you want others to use your app, then you will have to get a _valid_ certificate.)

Comment: @cbroe my this site is by default of non ssl - http://joomla.programminghelp24.com/ so what u meant by calling that page outside of facebook?

Comment: I meant calling `https://joomla.programminghelp24.com/` directly in your browser …

Comment: @CBroe Yes as usually i get untrusted connection error and i am prompted for the "add exception" rule acceptance but anyway i want everybody access it, so i end up by having purchasing ssl certificate which was obvious i thought?

Comment: Yes of course you have to get a valid SSL certificate … but if that was obvious to you, then what are you asking here …?

Comment: I thought if there would be any alternatives without purchasing ssl certificates by money

Comment: Well, you could get a free SSL cert, but unless your users accept that cert it still won't work for them due to mixed content / SSL validation errors

Answer (score 0):

Hey you Need A SSL Certificate to Make your app on the facebook.
You Need to Buy a SSL cert to programminghelp24.com

Dont take Normal SSL because the wont Support Subdomains.

Take Wildcard SSL Certificate.

And make the Canvas Url https://joomla.programminghelp24.com/

It Will Work

Comment: Hey professional. Take wildcart ssl for your site . it will load in facebook app in secure mode.

Comment: oops i think ssl certificate need good amount of money so not thinking to spend right now